# Oracle sql update query to sum columns rowwise

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write update statement for columns  rowwise but am getting error.

Ex:
[image]

I need to sum from col1 to col5 for each row and update it in column 6.

If i try something like:

```
UPDATE TABLE_DASH
SET COL6=sum(to_number(replace(nvl(col1,0),',',''))+to_number(replace(nvl(col2,0),',',''))+to_number(replace(nvl(col3,0),',',''))+to_number(replace(nvl(col4,0),',',''))+to_number(replace(nvl(col5,0),',','')) where pk=1
```

It throws group function not allowed error.

Comment: Please include your data and expected result as text, not images. Are you expecting the same value for `COL6` for all rows; or the total of the other columns just for that row? If the latter - which seems more likely - you don't need or want the `sum()` aggregate at all, so just remove that. You might also want to look at making `COL6` a virtual column so you don't have to keep it updated. And why are you storing numbers as strings?

Comment: Sum is aggregation function witch you may use in select statement to aggregate values from more than one row. You do not need it in this case because you process one row. Anyway it does'nt work in update without select.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `SUM` keyword. You're *summing* values with the `+` operator.

```
UPDATE TABLE_DASH
   SET COL6 =
            TO_NUMBER (REPLACE (NVL (col1, 0), ',', ''))
          + TO_NUMBER (REPLACE (NVL (col2, 0), ',', ''))
          + TO_NUMBER (REPLACE (NVL (col3, 0), ',', ''))
          + TO_NUMBER (REPLACE (NVL (col4, 0), ',', ''))
          + TO_NUMBER (REPLACE (NVL (col5, 0), ',', ''))
 WHERE pk = 1
```

Comment: one more question, for null values to_number throws error like invalid number, how can i handle it here? i tried nvl but it throws error for null

Comment: NVL isn't a culprit here; data you stored into VARCHAR2 column is. When dealing with numbers, store them as numbers, not strings. Because, if someone put e.g. 123,A5 into a column, it would be a valid string but you can't convert it to NUMBER value and that's why Oracle returned the INVALID NUMBER error. NVL doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: actually that's how the requirement it. the string needs to be converted to number and then added up.